# Why oci_fetch_array($stid) don't return the first row of oracle database table

Tags: php, oracle

I'm trying to make a search form that return some data from an oracle database,it works fine except that it skip the first row of table .
I used the following code :

```
enter code here
if(isset($_POST['search']) && !empty($_POST["search_box"])){
$name=$_POST['search_box'];
$sql='SELECT deejays.name,available_dates.data, available_dates.venue,available_dates.location FROM deejays,available_dates';
$sql .=" WHERE deejays.name ='{$name}'";
$sql .=' AND pk_id=fk_id';
$verify="SELECT  deejays.name FROM deejays WHERE deejays.name ='{$name}'";
$stid = oci_parse($conn,$sql );
oci_execute($stid);
if (oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)){
echo "<table width=\"100%\" align=\"center\" cellpadding=\"5\" cellspacing=\"5\">
<tr class=\"source\">
    <td colspan=3 align=\"center\"><h1>The facebook tour dates for ".$name." are:</h1></td>
</tr>
<tr align=\"center\" class=\"source1\">

    <td><strong>DATA</strong></td>
    <td><strong>VENUE</strong></td>
    <td><strong>LOCATION</strong></td>
</tr>";?>
<?php while($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)){ ?>
<tr align="center" class="rows">

    <td ><?php echo $row['DATA'];?></td>
    <td ><?php echo $row['VENUE'];?></td>
    <td ><?php echo $row['LOCATION'];?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
<?php } else {
            $stid = oci_parse($conn,$verify );
            oci_execute($stid);
            if (oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS))
             { echo "This artist hasn't records on facebook/bandsintown<br>  
enter code here
```

the expected result is:
[image]

and the real result is:
[image]

The second image shows that the first row is skipped,how could I solve this?Thanks in advance

Comment: Your first call `if(oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS))` will return the first row and move the cursor to the next row. So, your `while` loop will start at the second row.

Comment: and how can I make it to start at first row again?

Comment: Don't. Just iterate once over all lines. In the first line, check for a boolean that keeps track of wether you've already printed the table header or not. Then print the table header. Or not.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented, `oci_fetch_array()` will return an array containing the next result-set row of a query. Which means everytime you call it, the cursor will move to the next row. I have two suggestions.

**First**

Load all the result into an array after `oci_execute()`. And count the array if it has any row.

```
oci_execute($stid);
$result = array();

while($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS))
{
    $array[] = $row;
}
//check if result is not empty
if (count($result)) {
   //the table part here.
}
```

And when you want to display it in html table, use `foreach` loop to iterate the array and build the `<tr>`.

```
<?php foreach($result as $row) { ?>

    <tr align="center" class="rows">
        <t ><?php echo $row['DATA'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['VENUE'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['LOCATION'];?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

**SECOND**

You can use `oci_fetch_all()` to load all the rows from the query into an array.

```
oci_execute($stid);
//$result will have all the result of the current query
$count = oci_fetch_all($stid, $result);

if ($count) {
//table part here
}
```

And building the `<tr>` will be the same as the first.

Another way is to use buffered query. But this will depend on many factors.